# Using NamedPipes from a DLL to a single server

Tags: vb.net

Do the names of a bidirectional NamedPipe in a DLL in different applications and all communicating to a single server need to be unique or will a common name work?
i.e. (App1 with DLL pipename "DLL1" to Server, App2 with DLL pipename "DLL1" to Server) or (App1 with Dll pipename "DLL1" to Server, App2 with DLL pipename "DLL2" to Server)